# Запретить изменение размера ScrollView в StoryBoard xcode

Tags: ios

Добавляю ScrollView, подгоняю его под размеры View (на весь экран) при помощи constraints (0 со всех сторон). В ScrollView добавляю ImageView, устанавливаю ему размеры, равные ScrollView (со всех сторон = 0 до границ ScrollView). Устанавливаю Mode = Aspect Fit. Но, почему-то, при добавлении в ImageView изображения, большего чем размер экрана, ScrollView так же увеличивается (выходит за границы экрана). Мне нужно прокручивать изображение только по-горизонтали. То есть оно должно масштабироваться под размер ScrollView и если в ширину оказывается больше размера экрана - скроллиться по-горизонтали.
Хотелось бы сделать все это прямо в StoryBoard xcode.
PS Хочу добавить простую прокрутку изображений по-горизонтали на экран при минимальном написании кода. Все это только в портретной ориентации.

Comment: изображение добавляете тоже в IB или во время выполнения?

Comment: Во время выполнения. У меня будет набор изображений, которые будут попадать в этот ImageView. Хочется чтобы работало на устройствах с разными экранами. И чтобы можно было использовать одно большое изображение, которое просто будет масштабироваться.. Надеюсь я понятно объяснил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился. Я добавил в `ScrollView` сначала `View`, а уже в него - `ImageView`. Установил ширину и высоту `View` равными ширине и высоте родительского для `ScrollView View` (того, что над `ScrollView`).